# Complete coverage path planning

Tags: python

I am trying to write some python code from the scratch.

This code needs to make a robot (represented as a node) cover all the work space and avoid obstacles (there's an a priori knowledge of the location of the obstacles).

I figured out that the work space can be represented as a system of matrix.

Using wavefront distance transform (as shown in this figure:     http://www.emeraldinsight.com/content_images/fig/0490390507009.png)

How can I write a code such that robot moves from one node to the next highest value node, while keeping track of the visited nodes?

Thanks

EDIT: This is the python code that I got online (I have mid-level programming skills) that I am trying to adapt into making the boustrophedon motion (back and forth) with the aid of wavefront distance transform.

The code is currently getting stuck in the first row (x=0 and y=0), trying to move to the next rows and run through the highest node values.

try:
    import numpy
except:
    print "The numpy math library is not installed."
import time

class waveFrontPlanner:

```
def __init__(self, map, slow=False):
    self.__slow = slow
    self.__map = map
    if str(type(map)).find("numpy") != -1:
        #If its a numpy array
        self.__height, self.__width = self.__map.shape
    else:
        self.__height, self.__width = len(self.__map), len(self.__map[0])

    self.__nothing = 0
    self.__wall = 999
    self.__goal = 1
    self.__path = "PATH"

    #Robot value
    self.__robot = 254
    #Robot default Location
    self.__robot_x = 0
    self.__robot_y = 11

    #default goal location
    self.__goal_x = 18
    self.__goal_y = 0

    #temp variables
    self.__counter = 0
    self.__steps = 0 #determine how processor intensive the algorithm was

    #when searching for a node with a lower value
    self.__maximum_node = 250
    self.__max_node_location = 250
    self.__reset_max = 250 #above this number is a special (wall or robot)
###########################################################################

def run(self, prnt=False):
    """
    The entry point for the robot algorithm to use wavefront propagation.

    """

    path = []
    while self.__map[self.__robot_x][self.__robot_y] != self.__goal:
        if self.__steps > 20000:
            print "Cannot find a path."
            return
        #find new location to go to
        self.__new_state = self.propagateWavefront()
        #update location of robot
        if self.__new_state == 1:
            self.__robot_x -= 1
            if prnt:
                print "Move to x=%d y=%d\n\n" % \
                    (self.__robot_x, self.__robot_y)
            path.append((self.__robot_x, self.__robot_y))
        if self.__new_state == 2:
            self.__robot_y += 1
            if prnt:
                print "Move to x=%d y=%d\n\n" % \
                    (self.__robot_x, self.__robot_y)
            path.append((self.__robot_x, self.__robot_y))
        if self.__new_state == 3:
            self.__robot_x += 1
            if prnt:
                print "Move to x=%d y=%d\n\n" % \
                    (self.__robot_x, self.__robot_y)
            path.append((self.__robot_x, self.__robot_y))
        if self.__new_state == 4:
            self.__robot_y -= 1
            if prnt:
                print "Move to x=%d y=%d\n\n" % \
                    (self.__robot_x, self.__robot_y)
            path.append((self.__robot_x, self.__robot_y))
        self.__old_state = self.__new_state
    msg = "Found the goal in %i steps:\n" % self.__steps
    msg += "Map size= %i %i\n\n" % (self.__height, self.__width)
    if prnt:
        print msg
        self.printMap()
    return path
###########################################################################

def propagateWavefront(self, prnt=False):
    """


    """

    #self.unpropagate()
    #Old robot location was deleted, store new robot location in map
    self.__map[self.__robot_x][self.__robot_y] = self.__robot
    self.__path = self.__robot
    #Start location to begin scan at goal location
    self.__map[self.__goal_x][self.__goal_y] = self.__goal
    counter = 0
    while counter < 200:  #allows for recycling until robot is found
        x = 0
        y = 0
        time.sleep(0.00001)
        #while the map hasnt been fully scanned
        while x < self.__height and y < self.__width:
            #if this location is a wall or the goal, just ignore it
            if self.__map[x][y] != self.__wall and \
                self.__map[x][y] != self.__goal:
                #a full trail to the robot has been located, finished!
                maxLoc = self.maxSurroundingNodeValue(x, y)
                if maxLoc < self.__reset_max and \
                    self.__map[x][y] == self.__robot:
                    if prnt:
                        print "Finished Wavefront:\n"
                        self.printMap()
                    # Tell the robot to move after this return.
                    return self.__max_node_location
                #record a value in to this node
                elif self.__maximum_node != self.__reset_max:
                    #if this isnt here, 'nothing' will go in the location
                    self.__map[x][y] = self.__maximum_node + 1
            #go to next node and/or row
            y += 1
            if y == self.__width and x != self.__height:
                x += 1
                y = 0
        #print self.__robot_x, self.__robot_y
        if prnt:
            print "Sweep #: %i\n" % (counter + 1)
            self.printMap()
        self.__steps += 1
        counter += 1
    return 0
###########################################################################

#def unpropagate(self):
    """
    clears old path to determine new path
    stay within boundary

    """

    #for x in range(0, self.__height):
        #for y in range(0, self.__width):
            #if self.__map[x][y] != self.__wall and self.__map[x][y] != self.__goal:
                #self.__map[x][y] = self.__path
                #if this location is a wall or goal, just ignore it
                #clear that space
###########################################################################

def maxSurroundingNodeValue(self, x, y):
    """
    this method looks at a node and returns the lowest value around that
    node.

    """

    #reset minimum
    self.__maximum_node = self.__reset_max

    if y > 0 and x < (self.__height - 1):
        if self.__map[x][y-1] < self.__maximum_node and self.__map[x+1][y] < self.__maximum_node and\
        self.__map[x][y-1] != self.__wall and self.__map[x+1][y] != self.__wall:
            if self.__map[x][y-1] >= self.__map[x+1][y]:
                self.__maximum_node = self.__map[x][y-1]
                self.__max_node_location = 4

            else:
                self.__maximum_node = self.__map[x+1][y]
                self.__max_node_location = 3

    if y < self.__width - 1 and x < self.__height - 1:
        if self.__map[x][y+1] < self.__maximum_node and self.__map[x+1][y] <      self.__maximum_node:
            if self.__map[x][y+1] >= self.__map[x+1][y]:
                self.__maximum_node = self.__map[x][y+1]
                self.__max_node_location = 2

            else:
                self.__maximum_node = self.__map[x+1][y]
                self.__max_node_location = 3

    if x > 0 and y > 0:
        if self.__map[x-1][y] < self.__maximum_node and self.__map[x][y-1] < self.__maximum_node:
            if self.__map[x-1][y] >= self.__map[x][y-1]:
                self.__maximum_node = self.__map[x-1][y]
                self.__max_node_location = 1

            else:
                self.__maximum_node = self.__map[x][y-1]
                self.__max_node_location = 4

    if y < self.__width - 1 and x > 0:
        if self.__map[x-1][y] < self.__maximum_node and  self.__map[x][y+1] <   self.__maximum_node:
            if self.__map[x-1][y] >= self.__map[x][y+1]:
                self.__maximum_node = self.__map[x-1][y]
                self.__max_node_location = 1

            else:
                self.__maximum_node = self.__map[x][y+1]
                self.__max_node_location = 2         
    return self.__maximum_node
###########################################################################

def printMap(self):
    """
    Prints out the map of this instance of the class.

    """

    msg = ''
    for temp_B in range(0, self.__height):
        for temp_A in range(0, self.__width):
            if self.__map[temp_B][temp_A] == self.__wall:
                msg += "%04s" % "[X]"
            elif self.__map[temp_B][temp_A] == self.__robot:
                msg += "%04s" % "o"
            elif self.__map[temp_B][temp_A] == self.__goal:
                msg += "%04s" % "G"
            else:
                msg += "%04s" % str(self.__map[temp_B][temp_A])
        msg += "\n\n"
    msg += "\n\n"
    print msg
    #
    if self.__slow == True:
        time.sleep(0.05)
```

#

if **name** == "**main**":
    """
    X is vertical, Y is horizontal

```
"""

floormap = [[19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19], \
         [18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18], \
         [17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17], \
         [16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16], \
         [15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15], \
         [14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14], \
         [13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13], \
         [12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12], \
         [11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,12], \
         [10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,12], \
         [9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,10,11,12], \
         [8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,10,11,12], \
         [7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,9,10,11,12], \
         [6,6,6,6,6,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], \
         [5,5,5,5,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], \
         [4,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], \
         [3,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], \
         [2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], \
         [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]] 


start = time.time()
planner = waveFrontPlanner(floormap, False)
#time.sleep(2)
planner.run(True)
end = time.time()
print "Took %f seconds to run wavefront simulation" % (end - start)
```

Comment: This just sounds like a list of requirements... Have you tried to solve this yourself? Is there any code you have already written that you can share with us?

Answer (score 0):

1. Keep your grid inside a matrix with each node having the information you need: value, is it an obstacle, etc.
2. An approach would be to use Depth First Search to get all possible paths, and pick the highest value route from the ones that lead you to the end.

Rant: This question is marked as Node.js, you should remove the tag since it has no relation what so ever.